# detect page from shebang in url with php or javascript

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, shebang

In a PHP file, i am using a javascript to integrate Spreadshop app into my website.

When an user clicks on an article, it display the article using an URL like this:

```
https://www.example.com/#!-A108148940
```

I need to extract the article ID from this url ( 108148940 ) to display an image ( /images/108148940.jpg ) using PHP or Javascript, but only if we are currently viewing the article page (i.e. look for #!-A in the url)

This is the first time i'm forced to use shebang. Why isn't there an easy way to extract the variable just like $_GET['whatever'] with php ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP, being a server-side scripting language, won't be able to see the location's hash when the page loads; it's only available to the browser and its client.

Luckily, you can use JavaScript. Here's a fully mocked up example:

```js
var articleId = null;

var noArticleMsgEl = document.getElementById('no-article-msg');
var articleEl = document.getElementById('article');
var imgEl = document.getElementById('img');
var idLabelEl = document.getElementById('id-label');
var hashLabelEl = document.getElementById('hash-label');

var updateUi = function() {
  if (articleId) {
    noArticleMsgEl.style.display = 'none';
    article.style.display = 'block';
    imgEl.src = 'http://lorempixel.com/' + articleId + '/' + articleId;
    idLabelEl.innerText = articleId || 'null';
    hashLabelEl.innerText = window.location.hash || 'null';
  }
}

var handleHashChange = function() {
  var hash = window.location.hash;
  if (hash) {
    var hashMatches = window.location.hash.match(/#!-A(\d+)/)
    var newArticleId = hashMatches && hashMatches[1] || null;
    if (articleId !== newArticleId) {
      articleId = newArticleId;
      updateUi();
    }
  }
};

// Listen and execute if the hash changes
window.addEventListener('hashchange', handleHashChange);

// Execute once on page load
handleHashChange();
```

```css
#no-article-msg {
  color: #444;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
}

#article {
  display: none;
  border: 1px solid #666;
  border-radius: 2px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
}

#img {
  width: 75px;
  height: 75px;
  background: #fafafa;
}
```

```html
Click One:
<a href="#!-A101">Article 101</a> | 
<a href="#!-A152">Article 152</a> | 
<a href="#!-A200">Article 200</a> | 
<a href="#!-A164">Article 164</a>

<br><br>
<div id="no-article-msg">No Article Loaded.</div>
<article id="article">
  <img id="img" /><br>
  <small><u>Current Hash:</u> <span id="hash-label"></span></small><br>
  <small><u>Current Article Id:</u> <span id="id-label"></span></small><br>
</article>
```

Comment: Any workaround if the location's hash isn't found when the page loads ? see other comment under the other post

Comment: @comdex You can listen for hashchanges and invoke the functionality both on the change and initially. I've updated my answer with a fully functional mockup; Just click "Run code snippet" on your desktop browser.

Comment: Thank you so much !

Answer (score 0):

This can be accomplished in both languages by using a split like function.  Split and explode will divide a string about a character.  So then we can get the second index:

**JavaScript**

There is a very handy built in way in JavaScript, `window.location.hash`.

```
console.log(window.location.hash);
```

Answer (score 0):

`window.location.hash` should hold the information you require; however, you can write a function to accept it or a string:

```js
console.log( getArticle('https://www.example.com/#!-A108148940') );
console.log( getArticle(window.location.hash) ); // may be null


function getArticle(url) {
  var re = new RegExp(/#!\-A(\d+)$/);
  if ( re.test(url) )
    return RegExp.$1;
  return null;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This seems to work, ID is displayed in console but only if the page is loaded using deeplink URL (like the one in the example). It doesn't work if someone goes to the root of the domain, then click on an article, the page is loaded using shebang without a real refresh of the page, so javascript trigger is loaded only once during first page load. Is there any workaround for this ? Here's a live example: https://www.weedstreetwear.com/

Comment: You may need to capture dynamic hash changes.

Comment: how to do this ?